# How to clean up RootConnector in phantom-dsl?

Tags: phantom-dsl

In phantom-dsl version 1.12.2, what is the mechanism to close/shutdown/cleanup resources after finishing talking with Cassandra when using the RootConnector way of connecting to a Cassandra cluster?

Answer (score 1):

This is an example:

```
object Whatever extends DatabaseProvider {

    private[this] def shutdownCassandra(): Unit = {
      com.websudos.phantom.Manager.shutdown()
      database.session.close()
      database.session.getCluster.close()
    }
}
```

To understand what `DatabaseProvider` is, have look [here](http://blog.websudos.com/2015/04/04/a-series-on-phantom-part-1-getting-started-with-phantom/).

**Update**

As of phantom 1.15.0, there is a `shutdown` method available by default on any `Database` object.